# Let lookup return an array of multi rows and multi columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table C3:E6 as follows.

Given H3:H4, I would like to get their corresponding columns in C3:E6.

I tried in N3 the formula `=XLOOKUP(H3:H4,C3:C6,D3:E6,,0)`, it returned only the first corresponding column rather than 2 columns.

Does anyone know how to write **only one** array formula covering several rows to return all the corresponding columns?

PS: I would prefer solutions without VBA and without LAMBDA function, which is still in preview mode.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the following:
`=INDEX(D3:E6,MATCH(H3:H4,C3:C6,0),SEQUENCE(1,2))`

Or if it may contain blank values and don't want them displayed as null:
`=SUBSTITUTE(INDEX(D3:E6,MATCH(H3:H4,C3:C6,0),SEQUENCE(1,2)),"","")`

[image]

Comment: It works, I  use `=INDEX(D3:E6,XMATCH(H3:H4,C3:C6,0),SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS(D3:E6)))`. Thank you.

Comment: Nice, please note that a blank value would return `0` without wrapping it in SUBSTITUTE as in example.

Comment: I'm aware of that.

Comment: If you use XMATCH you could also drop the `,0`. It defaults to exact match.

Comment: I just realized that `SUBSTITUTE` converts a number to a text that cannot be summed by `SUM` (it returns `0`). Pay attention to that when somebody uses `SUBSTITUTE`.

Comment: If you put it like this it works `=SUM(TextRange*1)`, but the blank cell will throw error.